# Why Use "Conventional" Travel to Get to the Tonks' House?

Tags: harry-potter

In the Battle of the Seven Harrys, they leave in seven pairs from Privet Drive and fly or ride to the Tonks' house (or to the Burrow in the movie).  It's clear the Death Eaters knew where Harry was leaving from and, when they followed, they'd also know where they were going, too.  (Or would stand a good chance of knowing.)

Why would it not have been safer to apparate, either to go straight to the Tonks' house, arriving just outside of any area protected magically, or to apparate to someplace closer, so the distance they'd have to travel would be shorter?

Even if apparition were traceable, if everything were set up and ready in an intermediate location, and Harry apparated there, they could leave immediately, finishing a spell as they leave to prevent apparition so the Death Eaters couldn't appear there until they got away.

A special portkey might also have been set up for such a situation, as well, to get Harry out of a known location and to somewhere else so he could be well on his way before the Death Eaters were able to catch up with him.

So why did they travel using the methods they did use?

Comment: Or I guess they could have just flown on the backs of eagles straight to Mount Doom....

Comment: Related: [Can the Trace detect apparition?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/10901)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Moody tells Harry before they leave that:

> Pius Thicknesse has gone over, which gives us a big problem. He’s made
>   it an imprisonable offense to connect this house to the Floo Network,
>   place a Portkey here, or Apparate in or out.

So if Harry apparated away from his house, he (and the rest of the Order) would be committing a crime.  They weren't ready to make an open break with the Ministry.

Comment: Thanks -- until I get my books back, I'm at a disadvantage.  Is there any reason given why they weren't able to apparate once they left the house?

Comment: @TangoOversway At that point Harry is still underage, and therefore subject to the Trace (used to detect magic performed by underage witches and wizards). They *could* have Apparated, or used other means of magical transport, but Voldemort would probably have found out where they'd gone to immediately.